# how to fix IComparable<T> while creating a priority queue

Tags: c#

this is a priority queue that I found at GitHub

```
 public class PriorityQueue<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        private List<T> data;

        public PriorityQueue()
        {
            this.data = new List<T>();
        }

        public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            data.Add(item);
            int ci = data.Count - 1; // child index; start at end
            while (ci > 0)
            {
                int pi = (ci - 1) / 2; // parent index
                if (data[ci].CompareTo(data[pi]) >= 0) break; // child item is larger than (or equal) parent so we're done
                T tmp = data[ci]; data[ci] = data[pi]; data[pi] = tmp;
                ci = pi;
            }
        }

        public T Dequeue()
        {
            // assumes pq is not empty; up to calling code
            int li = data.Count - 1; // last index (before removal)
            T frontItem = data[0];   // fetch the front
            data[0] = data[li];
            data.RemoveAt(li);

            --li; // last index (after removal)
            int pi = 0; // parent index. start at front of pq
            while (true)
            {
                int ci = pi * 2 + 1; // left child index of parent
                if (ci > li) break;  // no children so done
                int rc = ci + 1;     // right child
                if (rc <= li && data[rc].CompareTo(data[ci]) < 0) // if there is a rc (ci + 1), and it is smaller than left child, use the rc instead
                    ci = rc;
                if (data[pi].CompareTo(data[ci]) <= 0) break; // parent is smaller than (or equal to) smallest child so done
                T tmp = data[pi]; data[pi] = data[ci]; data[ci] = tmp; // swap parent and child
                pi = ci;
            }
            return frontItem;
        }

        public T Peek()
        {
            T frontItem = data[0];
            return frontItem;
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return data.Count;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; ++i)
                s += data[i].ToString() + " ";
            s += "count = " + data.Count;
            return s;
        }

        public bool IsConsistent()
        {
            // is the heap property true for all data?
            if (data.Count == 0) return true;
            int li = data.Count - 1; // last index
            for (int pi = 0; pi < data.Count; ++pi) // each parent index
            {
                int lci = 2 * pi + 1; // left child index
                int rci = 2 * pi + 2; // right child index

                if (lci <= li && data[pi].CompareTo(data[lci]) > 0) return false; // if lc exists and it's greater than parent then bad.
                if (rci <= li && data[pi].CompareTo(data[rci]) > 0) return false; // check the right child too.
            }
            return true; // passed all checks
        } // IsConsistent
```

I have create an adge class like this:

```
 public class Node
    {
        long x;
        long y;
        public long parent;
        public long rank;

        public Node(long a, long b, long c)
        {
            x = a;
            y = b;
            parent = c;
            rank = 0;
        }
    }

public class Edge : IComparable<Edge>
{
    public long u;
    public long v;
    public double weight;

    public Edge(long a, long b, double c)
    {
        u = a;
        v = b;
        weight = c;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Edge e1, Edge e2)
    {
        return e1.weight < e2.weight ? -1 : 1;
    }



    public int CompareTo(Edge other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

when I try to create an instance form priority queue class with edges I have an error like this:

```
 PriorityQueue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<Edge>();
```

The type 'A4.Edge' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PriorityQueue'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'A4.Edge' to 'System.IComparable
***how can I fix this?***

Comment: By implementing `IComparable` from `Edge` ? Anyway when you provide a `Comparer` to your quue you have to **use** it. It´s not magically invoked by `CompareTo` unless told so. Having said this I assume you won´t need to provide a `Comparer` at all, but just implement the interface from `Edge`-class.

Answer (score 1):

As of the defintion of your `PriorityQueue`-class `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`. Your `Edge`-class does not implement that interface, so you get the compiler-error-

Your `Edge`-class has to provide some way in order to compare an instance of it with another instance. That's done by implementing the `IComparable<T>`-interface:

```
public class Edge : IComparable<Edge>
{
    public long u;
    public long v;
    public double weight;

    public Edge(long a, long b, double c)
    {
        u = a;
        v = b;
        weight = c;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Edge other)
    {
        // your comparison here
    }
 }
```

Now as your class already provide some mechanism to make it comparable you won´t need to provide a `Comparer` to your `PriorityQueue`-class at all. In fact you don´t even use it in your code, so omit the parameter from the constructor:

```
PriorityQueue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<Edge>();
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply,but how can I fix this?PriorityQueue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparer<Edge>());@HimBromBeere

Comment: public class Edge :IComparable
        {
            public long u;
            public long v;
            public double weight;

            public Edge(long a, long b, double c)
            {
                u = a;
                v = b;
                weight = c;
            }

            public int CompareTo(Edge e1, Edge e2)
            {
                return e1.weight < e2.weight ? -1 : 1;
            }

            public int CompareTo(object obj)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

Comment: "`,but how can I fix this?PriorityQueue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparer<Edge>());`" By using `PriorityQueue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<Edge>();` as I already mentioned in my answer. Your class doesn´t use the comparer at all, so you won´t need to provide it. Omit the paramerter from the constructor.

Comment: Error CS0311 The type 'A4.Edge' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PriorityQueue<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'A4.Edge' to 'System.IComparable<A4.Edge> I've got this error @HimBromBeere

Comment: Seems like your `Edge`-class still does not implement `IComparable<T>` (the generic version), but only `IComparable` (the un-generic one).

Comment: Then plese update your question with your actual code. It´s hard to read from the comments.

Comment: @HimBromBree thank you so much ,soooooooooooo much, you helped me a lot,can I have a consultation with you?